# R - Wrong value assigning "mins" difftime to "secs" vector

Tags: r, difftime

I have a difftime of "x mins". When I assign it to a vector that is configured as difftime/secs, it doesn't convert the value, returning "x secs" instead of "60x secs"

Is this a bug or by design? I was able to force it with the conversion below, but it seems too cluttered.

```
v[1] <- as.difftime(as.numeric(a, units="secs"), units="secs")
```

I'm using R 3.3.1.

Thank you!

```
> v
Time differences in secs
[1]    120    120   1937 259013     23
> a
Time difference of 1 mins
> v[1] <- a
> v
Time differences in secs
[1]      1    120   1937 259013     23
> v[1]
Time difference of 1 secs
```